# How do you get the centroids from the output of Mahout's kmeans?

Tags: output, mahout

When I run Mahout kmeans I seem to get the whole clustering, i.e. all vectors along with their cluster membership.

But instead I would like to have as an output the final centroids. I know, I could simply calculate the mean over the whole of the respective clusters. But since the algorithms needs to have the final centroids anyway, there should be a way to output them. Is there?

Can anyone tell me how Mahout kmeans can output the final centroids? Helpful answers are appreciated.